# How to import from module_utils when running VScode Debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, import, ansible

I'm trying to develop custom ansible modules using the VSCode Debugger and have run into an import problem.

My ansible role structure looks like this:

```
.
├── defaults
├── library
│   └── dl_script
├── meta
├── module_utils
│   ├── dl_script2
│   └── dl_script3
├── tasks
├── templates
└── vars
```

The way ansible works is that the library folder should be where we define custom modules, with the module_utils folder the location for supporting libraries.

When I run my role with ansible it works fine because the ansible packages is supporting these libraries and makes them available to the module, in this case `dt_script`.

When I try to run this in vscode it falls over.

```py
from ansible.module_utils.dt_script2 import DTScript2
from ansible.module_utils.dt_script3 import DTScript3
```

Error:

```
No module named 'ansible.module_utils.dt_script2'
```

What I'd like to do is figure out a way to import the code from the module_utils folder and make it do so only when it can't do it the ansible way.

I've had a go at doing this myself, but with no success:

```py
try:
    from ansible.module_utils.dt_script2 import DTScript2
    from ansible.module_utils.dt_script3 import DTScript3
except:
    from ..module_utils.dt_script2 import dt_script2
    from ..module_utils.dt_script3 import dt_script3
```

Error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

EDIT1:

I have a solution, but I don't like it.

```
try:
    from ansible.module_utils.dt_script2 import DTScript2
    from ansible.module_utils.dt_script3 import DTScript3
except:
    import sys
    import os
    # I don't like this, but it seems to be the only way to get VScode to look for these files. 
    sys.path.insert(0,os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('library', 'module_utils'))
    from dt_script2 import *
    from dt_script3 import *
```

The reason this works is the by default python only searches the dir and subdir of the place you are running the script from, or certain package locations, like pyenv if you have it. What I'm doing here is amending the path list object to include another path to check from.

Reason this is bad in my mind is that this relies on path manipulation, which makes this very reliant on the host pathing not being really odd. I'd much prefer a safer solution for this, but this is only for when people want to use vscode to debug it.

If anyone has a better solution I'd love to see it.

Comment: Have you tried `frommodule_utils.dt_script2 import DTScript2`?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT. Not luck. 


# code:
from module_utils.dt_script2

# Output:
No module named 'module_utils